Second hand MOKKA advice upkeep
Coffee MOKKA express side view2Afternoon
I was gifted a beautiful but very old coffee pot. I can make out it is a Mokka Express made in Italy and on the inner chamber a identifying number.
It works very well bar leaking in the water chamber when boiling (probably user error)
I was hoping to show the photo and ask if I could get rid of the markings or is it
More scuffing below
